# javascript only executes once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a cms page for my site. part of it is writing a preview component for my blog.  I have a form, and a preview button, that activates a Javascript, which places the html typed in the text-area in a div element to test it. Everything works fine but the problem is that it only works once for each pageload. So I can't test something, add some code and retest it. Any ideas how to make multiple testing possible ?

Code Form:

```
<form>
   <textarea rows="30"cols="30" name="blogpost" style="width:500px;resize:none;" autofocus placeholder="Enter your new blogpost here!"></textarea>
   </br>    
   <input type = "submit" value="post">
   <input type = "button" id="testknop" value="previeuw" onclick="previeuwpost(this.form, this.form.blogpost);">
   <input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function previeuwpost(form, text){
    $("#previeuwbox").replaceWith(text.value);
}
```

Thanks a lot folks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceWith` means replaced.
Therefore, after you click, the `$("#previeuwbox")` is gone.

Please use :

```
$("#previeuwbox").html(text.value);
```